# NodeJS Running multiple fetch requests inside multiple Node-Schedule jobs

Tags: node.js, node-fetch, node-schedule

My goal is to be able to run different functions in each of the multiple node schedule jobs, which will run at specific times of the day, and will call a specific function depending on the time of the day.

I have the following code, for a minimum example I have made it simple.

```
var f1 = function () {
    return fetch('url1.php', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
}

var f2 = function () {
    return fetch('url2.php', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
}
    var tasks = [f1, f2];

const promesas = async(tasks) => {
return await Promise.all(tasks.map(function (e, j) {

rules[j] = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rules[j].dayOfWeek = [new schedule.Range(1, 5)];
rules[j].hour = hours[j];
rules[j].minute = mins[j];

return schedule.scheduleJob(rules[j], async function () {
    try {
        await tasks[j]()
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
})).then(response => {
    return Promise.resolve(response);
    });
}

promesas(tasks);
```

I can run these functions just fine outside the jobs, or all within a single job. But not in the setup that I want which I describe at the beggining.

**The first iteration works fine**, the second just fails. The difference between each job is of one minute for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you're doing here, especially with your odd use of Promises. (Why `await` the `Promise.all()`? Why return `Promise.resolve()` of the already resolved `response`? Why `await` each individual task rather than just let it execute (or fail) asynchronously in what amounts to a cronjob script with no output?)

However, if this is working for you for the first iteration, that's fine.
Can I assume you're using [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule)? If so, just note that you're actually using times of day 00:00, 01:01, etc. rather than "one minute between each for testing purposes" as you claim.

Here's how I would do what you seem to be trying to do:

```js
const tasks = [f1, f2];

let i = 0;
for (let task of tasks) {
    let rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
    rule.dayOfWeek = [new schedule.Range(1, 5)];
    rule.minute = (new Date().getMinutes() + (++i)) % 60; // adjust to suit your needs
    schedule.scheduleJob(rule, task);
}
```

I have confirmed this works, e.g. issues one task per minute starting from the minute after the script is started. No `await`, `then`, or `Promise.all` is necessary for the simple example you have given, but may be required depending on what you plan to do with the results of each job function.